# How to display Months Name as header in a Matrix RDLC control as it is in a resultset?

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer

My stored procedure returns a result set like this.

[image]

I am using a Matrix Control in a RDLC Report. So the report looks like this.

[image]

You can see the month is not staring from Jan in the report. I would like to display the Columns as in the order of JAN,FEB,MAR.....etc. Can any one help me out with this?

Answer (score 1):

Set Sorting in the Grouping and Sorting Properties to sort by this expression:

```
=iif(Fields!DataSetField.Value = "ColumnName", "zzz", Fields!DataSetField.Value)
```

Where "zzz" could be a number or whatever you need it to be to help the sort and then select Direction as either Ascending or Descending base on this expression.

Answer (score 1):

1. you could modify your stored procedure to also resulting month as 1 - 12
2. or maybe add a calculated column that result 1 iif months == "jan" and so on...

Then you can specified sort by (the new integer type column) at column grouping.

Another way is directly set the sort by, using multiple iif:

```
=iif(Fields!Months.Value="JAN",1,(iif(Fields!Months.Value="FEB",2,([and so on..])))
```

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the Tablix header and select **Tablix Properties...**
Click on **Sorting**
Click on Add and enter the folowing formula:

```
=Month(Fields!Month.Value & " 01 2014")
```

Comment: I guess it's just a typo, but the bracket at the end should be after Month.Value